# Is it possible to implement global raw input?

Tags: raw-input, mouse-hook

I have two mice connected to my computer and I want to make a logger that distinguishes between these two.
The Low-Level Mouse hook doesn't supply me that information so I have thought about catching Raw Input messages in order to get the Device Instance Id of the mouse.
But unfortunately Raw Input register is limited for only my application!

Does someone have another idea how can I distinguish between the two mice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I just have to turn this flag on when I register the Raw Input events:
RIDEV_INPUTSINK
for more information
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645565(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)